# Lightweight method for drawing various shapes / text on the screen quickly in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, graphics, sdl

This is hopefully a really simple question!

Which method (and possibly library) is considered to be the best for drawing text and shapes, and modifying individual pixels, on a 2D canvas, such that I can achieve at least 30FPS? I already know of various methods, such as SDL, DirectX, WPF, Windows Forms Graphics etc, but I wondered which one I should spend most of my effort on learning in order to achieve my goal? Which one does the community respect the most?

Thanks very much,

Nick A Hill

Comment: Not a simple question at all. You mentioned a lot of different choices, and they're all valid. Choosing between them depends on your exact requirements and a lot more information than you've provided here. They'll all get shapes and text on the screen quickly. None is considered any better than the other, it would all be a matter of personal preference.

Comment: One that you didn't mention is XNA, which is a managed layer built on top of DirectX.  It's hard to recommend one over the other though based on the information available about your problem.  Is this a data visualization app? a game?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this as a fast graphics framework :

[Ultra Fast 2D & 3D Graphics Framework](http://xen.codeplex.com/) used even for game design in XBox and PC!

Its learning is easy for developers of other microsoft frameworks (like .net framework)

Comment: Let me clarify - I would like to be able to draw onto a 2D canvas in a GDI+ like way, with perhaps including at most one referenced DLL in the final project. The only other dependency should be on the .NET Framework redistributable. I'm not seeking an answer for a specific, single problem, but rather as a primary way of focussing all my future development (although if you are interested, I'd be working on games and games SDKs).

Comment: So then fastest solution for you should be Windows Forms Graphics. because uses low level libraries than wpf and also does not need more libraries than .net framework (like DirectX).

Comment: @Nicholas: The last comment is wrong. WinForms doesn't use any "lower level" libraries than WPF does. And everything required for a WPF application to run is included in a standard install of the .NET Framework. There's no functional or distributional difference between a WinForms and a WPF app. The misunderstandings that surround this issue are rife, but none of those issues should be relevant in your choice of one over the other.

Comment: @Cody look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timothyc/archive/2006/06/16/634638.aspx) and [this](http://www.leadtools.com/Help/LEADTOOLS/v15/DH/Wpf/TO/Leadtools.Wpf.Topics~Leadtools.Wpf.Topics.DifferencesBetweenGDIANDWPF.html) and [this](http://www.fernicola.org/loquitor/index.php?/archives/19-When-to-use-WPF-and-when-to-use-other-technologies.html#extended) to find more differences even in framework (specially in speed) between WPF, GDI and some others in this category. but remember the fastest is still XNA but in different category!

Comment: Where did I say that it was the same? I actually made two arguments. First, that WinForms doesn't draw at any "lower level" than WPF, mainly because that's a meaningless designation. Yes, it uses an entirely different set of frameworks for graphics rendering; I myself have made that point multiple times in various answers ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384192/), for example). Second, I made the argument that there is neither a distributional nor a functional difference between WinForms and WPF, which is the OP's primary concern. Both require only the .NET FW be installed.