# how to implement graphic acceleration

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an array of 36000 points and I'm drawing them on a canvas in a WPF.
It takes a lot of time for the CPU to draw it. I have seen alot of information online about GPU acceleration but I didn't find one example / tutorial on how to do this.

```
      foreach (Point myPoint in arr)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Height = 3;
            r.Width = 3;
            r.Fill = myBrush;
            drawingboard.Children.Add(r);
            Canvas.SetTop(r, Center.Y + myPoint.y * 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(r, Center.X + myPoint.x * 50);
        }
```

I want to know how to let the GPU do this work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384192/how-does-hardware-acceleration-work-with-wpf seems relevant

Comment: I've already read that, and that article says that I don't have to do anything to make the GPU offload the CPU, however when I run the application there is 17% CPU usage and about 0-1% GPU usage when I draw the points.

Comment: If you want true GPU acceleration, you'd probably want to look into a DirectX library.

Comment: Thanks , I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it a real answer, see [how does hardware acceleration work with wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384192/how-does-hardware-acceleration-work-with-wpf) but the short version is, if it can it will, of it cant it wont.. you dont have to do anything to change that.

Comment: Well, how can I tell if it will. I have 980ti I'm pretty sure I should get tier 2 rendering..